# UPDATED - Grouping dataframe in pandas while discarding rows after finding criteria

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe (more than 2 million values) similar to the following:

```
  Name  a  b  max
0   t1  1  0   10
1   t1  1  1   15
2   t1  1  1   25
3   t1  1  2   30
4   t1  1  1    5
5   t1  1  2   10
6   t1  1  3   35
7   t1  1  3   30
```

I need to group the dataframe with **name**, **a** and **b** but with the following rules:

1) For each group of **name** and **a** I have to discard all rows after the **max value** on the 4th column.

2) I'll them need to group **name**, **a**, and **b** and get rid of the duplicated values, using only the last ones.

I have a working solution when i fist get the max per group

```
max_df = df.loc[df.groupby(['name', 'a']).max.idxmax()]
```

them i have a function that runs on ever row of the group finding if the row is < than the row on the max_df for that group

lastly i get my result by doing:

```
result = df.drop_duplicates(['name','a','b'], keep="last")
```

The issue is step number 2 is reallyyyy slow, and needs to execute a function on every single row.

Is there a way to optimize step number 1? selecting the max value of a group and select the rows from the beginning of the group until the line of the max value?

The example dataframe can be created using:

```
data = [['t1', 1, 0, 10], ['t1', 1, 1, 15], ['t1', 1, 1, 25], ['t1', 1, 2, 30], ['t1', 1, 1, 5], ['t1', 1, 2, 10], ['t1', 1, 3, 35], ['t1', 1, 3, 30]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'a', 'b', 'max'])
```

The result expected for this example would be:

```
  Name  a  b  max                                                                                                                                               │····
0   t1  1  0   10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            │····
4   t1  1  1   5                                                                                                                                               │····
5   t1  1  2   10                                                                                                                                               │····
6   t1  1  3   35                                                                                                                                               │····
```

Comment: Do you just want the max of the `max` column by groups of name, a and b? It seems to me the output is the same as what you get with this `df.groupby(['Name', 'a', 'b'], as_index=False).agg({'max': lambda x: x.max()})` except that the index is not kept

Comment: If you are discarding all rows **after** the max value in the `max` column per group and then dropping duplicates based on the same groupby logic, then you will always be left with the single row per group that contains the max in the `max` column (assuming the `max` column is sorted).

Comment: my example was way to simple, i'm sorry for that, if the dataset is `data = [['t1', 1, 0, 10], ['t1', 1, 1, 15], [ 't1', 1, 1, 25], ['t1', 1, 2, 30], ['t1', 1, 1, 5], ['t1', 1, 2, 10], ['t1', 1, 3, 35], ['t1', 1, 3, 30]]` note that groups can appear again, and  I want to keep only the last gourp., on the new example lines 0, 4, 5, and 6

Comment: groups can repeat before the max value, i want to drop all lines **after** the max for that group, and keep the **last** value for each group before the max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted to do?

```py
import pandas as pd
data =[['t1', 1, 0, 10],
       ['t1', 1, 1, 15],
       ['t1', 1, 1, 25],
       ['t1', 1, 2, 30],
       ['t1', 1, 1, 5],
       ['t1', 1, 2, 10],
       ['t1', 1, 3, 35],
       ['t1', 1, 3, 30]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'a', 'b', 'max'])

# create a column with the indices but sort on ['Name', 'a']
# this allows you to get the last occurring position of the max for the group
# using x[::-1] to reverse is useful in case there are ties on the max
df = df.sort_values(['Name', 'a', 'b']).reset_index()
df['max_index'] = df.groupby(['Name', 'a'])['max'].transform(lambda x: x[::-1].idxmax())

# now you don't need to do anything by row
# you already have indices sorted but now you have the max on ['Name', 'a', 'b']
# you just need to take rows where index is less than what idxmax gave
df1 = df[df['index'] <= df['max_index']].copy()
df1 = df1.sort_values(['Name', 'a', 'b'])
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(['Name', 'a', 'b'], keep='last')
df1 = df1.drop('max_index', axis=1)
df1 = df1.set_index('index')
```

Output:

```py
Name  a  b  max
index                
0       t1  1  0   10
4       t1  1  1    5
5       t1  1  2   10
6       t1  1  3   35
```

What's interesting though is the max for [t1, 1, 2]. You want 10 and not 30?

Comment: yes! that is it! thanks! It's weird because they are consecutive readings, so it only matters measurements closest to the maximum value, all previous ones, even if higher don't matter. Keeping the id index for the max value and coping removing the old measurements was all that i needed!

Comment: No Problem at all. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

OK. now i got the question.
Here is what we need

```
a=df[df.index==df.groupby(['Name', 'a'])['max'].transform('idxmax')]
b=df[df.index<df.groupby(['Name', 'a'])['max'].transform('idxmax')]
b=b.groupby(['Name', 'a','b']).tail(1)
b = pd.merge(b, a,  how='outer')
b.drop_duplicates(subset='b',keep='last',inplace=True)
```

Lines 2&3 above can be combined as below as well

```
b=(df[df.index<df.groupby(['Name', 'a'])['max'].transform('idxmax')].groupby(['Name', 'a','b']).tail(1))
```

**Details**

```
a=df[df.index==df.groupby(['Name', 'a'])['max'].transform('idxmax')]
```

With this, we assign the max row (after grouped by 'Name' & 'a') to a dataframe named 'a' so that we can use it later.

```
b=df[df.index<df.groupby(['Name', 'a'])['max'].transform('idxmax')]
```

With this we get all the rows below the max value in the 'max' column

```
b=b.groupby(['Name', 'a','b']).tail(1)
```

With this we take the last item in each group from the dataframe that the rows below the max value in the 'max' column

```
b = pd.merge(b, a,  how='outer')
```

With this, we merge the last items in each group with the Max on the whole dataset

```
b.drop_duplicates(subset='b',keep='last',inplace=True)
```

Since the max of the whole dataset & the last time in each group are from one of the groups, we drop duplicates retaining the last one.

check it out

Comment: sorry, i guess my example was to simple, for example if the dataset is like this: `data = [['t1', 1, 0, 10], ['t1', 1, 1, 15], [ 't1', 1, 1, 25], ['t1', 1, 2, 30], ['t1', 1, 1, 5], ['t1', 1, 2, 10], ['t1', 1, 3, 35], ['t1', 1, 3, 30]]` the values that i want to keep are the last lines for that group, so on this dataset lines 0, 4, 5 and the max line 6

Comment: Do you mean 0, 4, 5 and 7? The last occurrence of group (t1, 1, 3) is row 7

Comment: i am confused. please update the question with the new data-set & expected output. add as many scenarios as possible & then the final output you want

Comment: so thas is my issue, for the group **name** and **a** the max value is on row 6, i need to keep that line and discard the rows after it, them i need to group by **name**, **a**, and **b**